# VirtualBox COM API - error creating cloned VM

Tags: com, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Trying the following code (C#) to create a cloned VM, but it fails:

```
VirtualBox.VirtualBox box = new VirtualBox.VirtualBox();

//create a new machine
IMachine machine = box.CreateMachine(null, "MyClone", null, null, "forceOverwrite=1");
box.RegisterMachine(machine);

//Lock machine for editing
machine.LockMachine(session, LockType.LockType_Write);
IMachine machsettings = session.Machine;

//clone the disk image from an existing vdi (source VDI is not being locked/used)
IMedium hddorig = box.OpenMedium("c:\\tmp\\VDI\\dsl-4.4.10-x86.vdi", DeviceType.DeviceType_HardDisk, AccessMode.AccessMode_ReadOnly, 0);
IMedium hddclone = box.CreateHardDisk("VDI", "c:\\tmp\\VDI\\clone.vdi");
IProgress hddprogress = hddorig.CloneTo(hddclone, 0, hddorig);
hddprogress.WaitForCompletion(-1);

//attach disk image to machine
machsettings.AddStorageController("IDE", StorageBus.StorageBus_IDE);
machsettings.AttachDevice("IDE", 0, 0, DeviceType.DeviceType_HardDisk, hddclone); //fails -  Storage for the medium 'c:\tmp\VDI\clone.vdi' is not created

machsettings.SaveSettings();
```

AttachDevice always fails saying "Storage for the medium is not created". What step am I missing here?

The following code works fine, so it looks like there is some issue creating hddclone.
    machsettings.AttachDevice("IDE", 0, 0, DeviceType.DeviceType_HardDisk, hddorig); //OK

thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the problem is caused by a known issue with VirtualBox keeping memory of old files around.

Workaround is to make sure the cloned vdi is always given a unique name e.g. by appending a timestamp to the filename.